# How can I validate/post col with edit type as select in jqgrid in form edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to send my form data (which contains 3 select(chosen) fields) to server while saving.

How can I do this? I'm not able to retrieve their values in any of the functions :

`beforeSubmit`,`onclickSubmit` and `beforeCheckValues`.

```
colNames:['Role','Department','Employee','City','employeeId','deptId'],
                colModel:[
                {name:"role", index:"role", width:200,editable:true, edittype:"select",formoptions:{rowpos:2},editoptions:{
                    style:"width:95%" ,
                    dataInit: function (elem) {

                        var optionBlank = document.createElement('option');
                        optionBlank.text = "Select Role" ;
                        optionBlank.value = "Select Role" ;
                        elem.add(optionBlank);

                        $(elem).addClass('roleChosen');
                        $(elem).chosen({search_contains:true});
                    }
                    }
                },
                {name:"dept", index:"dept", width:200,editable:true, edittype:"select",formoptions:{rowpos:1},editrules:{required:true},editoptions:{ 
                        style:"width:95%",
                        dataInit: function (elem) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/getDeptNames.json",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type:"POST",
                                async:false,
                                success: function(data, status){    

                                    var optionBlank = document.createElement('option');
                                     optionBlank.text = "Select Department" ;
                                     optionBlank.value = "Select Department" ;
                                    elem.add(optionBlank);

                                     for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
                                         var option = document.createElement('option');
                                        option.innerHTML = "<b>" +data[i].name + "</b>";
                                        option.value =data[i].deptId;
                                        elem.add(option);
                                     }


                                     $(elem).addClass('deptNameChosen');

                                    $(elem).chosen({search_contains:true});
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        dataEvents: [
                                     { type: 'change', fn: function(e) {                                    
                                     getRolesFromDept($('.deptNameChosen :selected').val());                //will populate role column
                                      },
                                     }
                                    ]
                    }
                },
                {name:"employee", index:"employee", width:150,editable:true,editrules:{required:true,custom: true,custom_func: empVldtnCheck},editoptions:{
                     style:"width:95%",
                     dataInit: function (elem) {

                                var autocompleteSource = function(request, response,term) { 

                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "empAutoComplete.json",
                                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        type: "GET",
                                        async:false,
                                        data : {
                                            featureClass : "P",
                                            style : "full",
                                            name_startsWith : request.term
                                        },
                                        success : function(data, status) {
                                        response($.map(data.details, function(item) {
                                            return {
                                                label : item.employeeName,
                                                value : item.employeeName,
                                                employeeId : item.employeeId
                                            };
                                        }));
                                    },
                                        error: function (res, status) {
                                            alert(res.status+" : "+res.statusText+". Status: "+status);
                                        }
                                    });//END AJAX
                                };
                               $(elem).autocomplete({
                                   autoFocus: true,
                                   source: autocompleteSource,
                                   position: {  collision: "flip"  },
                                   minLength: 3,
                                   select: function (a, b) {
                                       getCityForEmployee(b.item.employeeId);
                                   }
                               });//END AUOTOCOMPLETE 


                     }
                    },formatter:function(cellValue,options,rowObject){
                        return "<span class='hyperLink'>" +"<a target='_blank' href="+ rowObject.employeeURL +"?employee="+ encodeURI(rowObject.employee) +">"+rowObject.employee+"</a>"  + "</span>";
                        }
                },
                {name:"city", index:"city",editable:true,edittype:"select",editrules:{required:true}, editoptions : { 
                    style:"width:95%",
                    multiple:true,
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                         $(elem).addClass('cityChosen');
                            var optionBlank = document.createElement('option');
                            optionBlank.text = "Select Module" ;
                            optionBlank.value = "Select Module" ;
                            elem.add(optionBlank);

                        $(elem).chosen({search_contains:true});
                     }//END Dataint

                    }, width:200},
                {name:"employeeId",editable:false, index:"employeeId", hidden:true},
                {name:"deptId", index:"deptId",editable:false, hidden:true}

                ]
```

postData is only showing employee column data properly and not even showing any data for department and role and showing only value for city column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need *validate* the data you should first try with `editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: ...}` See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom_checking_example).

The callbacks like `beforeSubmit` contains `postdata` (the first parameter). It's object which properties are the names of columns which was edited. The values of the properties are the values which enter the user. So you need just examine `postdata`.

**UPDATED**: If you have wrong `postdata` in `beforeSubmit` then you should verify that ids of `<input>` and `<select>` fields of editing dialog have the same values like the values of `name` property of `colModel`. I'd recommend you to comment *temporary* parts of `dataInit` code. The usage of `dataUrl` is recommended in case of loading dynamic options of select and the usage of `value` is recommended for static values, like in `role` column.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. custom_func is not getting called with edittype:select. I am using this for 1 other column whose edittype is not select. I want to both validate and send the data to server.I am getting this result in beforeCheckValues method :-          posdata            Object {"": "NewYork", application: " ", userDtlGrid_id: "_empty"} .                        It is only showing 2 cols and that too not properly, colName not coming in front of NewYork as edittype is select.

Comment: @user2640846: jqGrid first call `beforeCheckValues` and then call `$.jgrid.checkValues` for every editable column. It's not important which `edittype` the column have.

Comment: I am not getting columnNames and values in postData in beforeCheckValues. Getting only for 1 column,not for all 4 columns.                                           Object {"": "NewYork", application: " ", userDtlGrid_id: "_empty"}

Comment: @user2640846: The value `"": "NewYork"` shows that you have wrong values in `colModel`. If you have some problems in specific columns you have to include the definition of the columns in `colModel`.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly wrong values can be? Yes I guess it is for specific columns only, it is working only for one column. include definition means?

Comment: the property names of `posdata` are the values of `name` property in `colModel`. You should append your question with `colModel` which you use. The `name` property of `colModel` is extremely important. It's like the `id` of the column. It should be unique. It will be used to construct another unique `id` values of the grid and editing form. The existence of `"": "NewYork"` inside of `postdata` shows that you have some **rough errors** in `colModel`.

Comment: what you posted don't corresponds to `postdata: {"": "NewYork", application: " ", userDtlGrid_id: "_empty"}`. `colModel` have editable columns `dept`, `role`, `employee`, `city`. So `postdata` should contains all the data. Instead of that you posted **absolutely another `postdata`. Moreover colModel have a lot of very strange code like Ajax calls with `async:false`, the usage of `edittype:"select"` without `values` or `dataUrl` in `editoptions` and so on. You should first simplify the code dramatically to make it working and only then include "advanced features".

Comment: Thanks Oleg. This is the main issue that postdata is not coming up with all columns,it is showing only 2 columns (only employee and city). edittype:select doesn't have any values or datainit because values will come dynamically.        postdata:{"": "NewYork" ,employee : "user12" , userDtlGrid_id: "_empty"}                 .This is the postdata I am getting and it is not showing all 4 cols .

Comment: You are welcome! The column `"role"` will be filled not dynamically. Why you not use just `value:"Select Role:Select Role"`? If you need to load the data from the server you can use `editoptions.dataUrl` and optionally `editoptions.buildSelect`. If you use [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) you can use [editoptions.selectFilled](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-callbacks-and-jQuery-events#new-selectfilled-callback-and-jqgridselectfilled-event) additionally. You should first comment all **optional parts** like `dataInit` and `dataEvents` and see `postData`.

Comment: I have to use jquery "chosen" plugin for selection as it allows both search and selecting from drop down i.e why I am using appending options like this and on selecting employee ,other options will populate.          select: function (a, b) {
                                 getCityForEmployee(b.item.employeeId);
                                }                     This method which is called on employee autocomplete select will populate city values dynamically.

Comment: If you want to find an error in complex program you should start with **temporary** commenting of all not required things. You can edit without  "chosen" plugin/ [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) or other. You need just find the reason **why posdata** are wrong. I recommend you additionally verify the ids of all input/select fields of editing dialog. All ids shoule be the same like the values of `name` properties of `editable: true` columns.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  My id's are same as names except they are prefixed with "tr_" like tr_employee and tr_city etc. Is it fine?

Comment: The prefix `"tr_"` have **the rows** in the form, but the `<input>` and `<select>` have just `id` equal to `name` in `colModel`. Now you should debug the code till `beforeCheckValues`. Which version of jqGrid (`jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) you use?

Comment: You should set breakpoins new `getFormData` calls (see `$("#sData", frmtb2).click(function(){...});`) and examine `postdata` which will be build.

Comment: By the way jqGrid 4.7.1 is not more free for commercial usage. I posted recently **free jqGrid 4.8** [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), see [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki). You can try it later after you will find the main reason of the current problem.

Comment: Thanks for id solution. My select's(city,department and role) doesn't have any id at all and input(employee) has id. I guess i.e. it is working for employee. Any idea why id's are not there for select?

Comment: Do you tried to comment `$(elem).chosen(...)` and verify the ids? You can validate `elem.id` in `dataInit`.

Comment: I just removed $(elem).chosen() from dataInit and kept option thing .It is not working. Then I commented whole dataInit and added values in "value" ,is's are coming fine now . But I have to use chosen,how can I do that ?

Comment: @user2640846: So which part of your code destroy `id`? You can start with simplest column like `"role"`. Can you include `$(elem).chosen(...)` not breaking `id` of select? You can use `value:"Select Role:Select Role"` inside of `editoptions` instead of your strange code with manual adding of option.

Comment: Thanks alot Oleg. Issue was with id's only. For default values ,I used value like        value:{"Select City":"Select City"} and initialized the chosen in dataInit .Earlier I was also creating options (for default values) in dataInit.and then on employee autocpmplete's select event I populated other options dynamically and called chosen:updated. By this time ,id was already created, so it didn't create any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used both "value" and "dataInit" of editoptions along with edittype:"select" to solve the issue.
value : for giving default values
dataInit : to initialize as chosen autocomplete/select.

- Correct Approach

  {
  name:"city", index:"city",editable:true,edittype:"select",editrules:{required:true},
       editoptions : { 
                      style:"width:95%",
                      value:{"Select City":"Select City"},

  ```
                  dataInit: function (elem) {
                       $(elem).addClass('cityChosen');
                           $(elem).chosen({search_contains:true}); 
                   }//END Dataint
                  }
  ```
- Wrong approach

  {name:"city", index:"city",editable:true,edittype:"select",editrules:{required:true},
   editoptions : { 
                  style:"width:95%",
                  dataInit: function (elem) {
      var optionBlank = document.createElement('option');
                              optionBlank.text = "Select City" ;
                              optionBlank.value = "Select City" ;
                              elem.add(optionBlank);

  ```
                   $(elem).addClass('cityChosen');
                       $(elem).chosen({search_contains:true}); 
               }//END Dataint
              }
  ```

2nd one will destroy id of select element.